# Building iOS static library

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a static library that depends on some of the Apple frameworks though when I include it as a target dependency I still need to add the frameworks it depends on to the application project. Is there some way to setup the project such that the dependencies only have to be specified in the static library target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm sure it is *possible*, you really don't want to do that. I'm not sure you'd be able to get accepted if you did that. The static library is linking against dynamic library, the symbols are not included in it like the .m files are. That is the whole point of dynamic libraries.

One solution is to use an xcconfig file.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/BasingBuildConfigurationsonConfigurationFiles.html

In this scenario you create a sharable xcconfig file that accompanies the static library. Then in your application project you copy the xcconfig file and base your application configuration on it.

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(SHARED_LDFLAGS) -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AudioToolbox ...
```

Comment: Yes thats more or less what I was looking for. I didn't really mean to statically link the dynamic libraries just a way for the application project to not have to manually add them all, but this config file seems like it can work well enough

Comment: Following this question, I created a new config file and added just the line that is mentioned in the answer. The static library that I am building compiles successfully but I still have to import the MapKit framework in my application project that uses my static library..Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Even if you link against a library, you still have to import the appropriate header files.